# Hyperlink on image using JS

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, javascript

I have a JavaScript variable that I need to be a clickable image.  I am able to get the image however I haven't been able to put a link on it.  Please help.

```
var vIconYellow =  "_layouts/images/KPIDefault-1.GIF";

var vIconGreen =  "_layouts/images/KPIDefault-0.GIF";
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to create dynamic clickable link elements.

Sample demo:

```
 <div id="CustomLink"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var vIconYellow = "/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-1.GIF";
        var vIconGreen = "/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-0.GIF";

        var link = $('<div><p><a href="' + vIconYellow + '" id="morelink"><img src="' + vIconYellow + '" alt="vIconYellow"></a></p><p><a href="' + vIconGreen + '" id="morelink"><img src="' + vIconGreen +'" alt="vIconGreen"></a></p></div>');
        $(link).appendTo("#CustomLink");
    })       
</script>
```